# PostgreSQL - Select from one table based on another

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have a table of tweets (@OneToMany) and another table of analyzedtweets (@ManyToOne) with 'n' number of analyzedtweets (one per analyst) for each entry in the tweet table.  Essentially, I can have any number of analysts (represented in a table), each one can analyze a tweet just once.  To make it a bit more complex, the entries in the tweet table are grouped by process which is represented by yet another table.

My question is, how would I query the analyzedtweet table for the tweet_id in the last entry given a specific process_id and analyst_id and then use that to find the next tweet in the tweet table also given the same process_id and analyst_id?  Basically, I want to give the analyst the next tweet that he/she has not yet analyzed within that specific process (run).

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tweet (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        process_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES process(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        ...
);


CREATE TABLE analyzedtweet (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        tweet_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tweet(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        analyst_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES analyst(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        process_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES process(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        ...
);


CREATE TABLE process (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        ...
);


CREATE TABLE analyst (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        ...
);
```

The only way I know how to do this is in 2 steps:

- Given a specific process_id (processId) and analyst_id (analystId) run the following query to give me the last tweet_id analyzed by that analyst in that process.

`SELECT tweet_id from analyzedtweet WHERE analyzedtweet.analyst_id = analystId AND analyzedtweet.process_id = processId ORDER BY analyzedtweet.tweet_id DESC LIMIT 1`

- Take the result of the above query (referred to ask latestTweetId) and run the following query:

`SELECT * from tweet WHERE tweet.id > latestTweetId AND tweet.process_id = processId ORDER BY tweet.id DESC LIMIT 1`

I'm sure there is a much better way to do this with JOIN, I just can't figure out how.

Finally, I am using Hibernate and would like to get the POJO back.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching the latest tweet for a giving process_id and analyzedtweet_id use this query:

```
List<Tweet> t = session.createQuery("select t from tweet t
           join t.process p,t.analyzedtweet a
           where p.id=? and a.id=? order by t.id desc")
            .setParameter(1, process_id)
            .setParameter(2, analyzedtweet_id)
            .setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
```

Comment: I think some of your fields are incorrect?  t.analyzedtweeet doesn't exist?  Tweet has a foreign key reference to process_id but that's it.